# Counting aggregated and then getting average

Tags: looker-studio

So, I am sure it's got to be simple, but, I cannot get Google Data Studio to provide an average of two aggregated columns. Example:

```
+----------+----------+
| Column 1 | Column 2 |
+----------+----------+
|    A     |   TRUE   |
|    A     |   FALSE  |
|    B     |   TRUE   |
|    C     |   FALSE  |
|    A     |   TRUE   |
|    C     |   TRUE   |
|    B     |   FALSE  |
|    B     |   TRUE   |
+----------+----------+
```

How can you get a count of the total value of `A` in `Column 1` and divide it by the total number of `TRUE` in `Column 2`? I have tried `Count(Column 1)/Count (Column 2)` but it gives me the totals for the other values as well.

I have tried creating a new field with a `CASE` statement, but there is an error when trying to divide the two resulting `CASE` `WHEN` values:

```
CASE
  WHEN Column 1 = A THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below shows two approaches of achieving the required calculation:

## Approach 1: Ratio Metrics

Using [Scorecards](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7193479), [Filters](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6291066) and [Ratio Metrics](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9457859):

**1) `Column 1 (A)` Scorecard**
- Add a Scorecard;
- *Drag and Drop* the field `Column 1` onto the *Metric* field and change the aggregation to `COUNT`;
- Create and apply the Filter: `Include Column 1 RegExp Match A`

**2) `Column 2 (TRUE)` Scorecard**
- Add a Scorecard;
- *Drag and Drop* the field `Column 2` onto the *Metric* field and change the aggregation to `COUNT`;
- Create and apply the Filter: `Include Column 2 RegExp Match TRUE`

**3) Ratio Metric**
- ***Select both Scorecards***: Click on the `Column 1 (A)` Scorecard and then Ctrl + Click on the `Column 2 (TRUE)` Scorecard Scorecard;
- ***Blend Data***: Right click on one of the selected Scorecards and select *Blend data* from the Drop-down.

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/e2fcf68c-3d56-45f2-aa6d-1f3ab972bcfb) to demonstrate, as well as a GIF showing the process:

[image: 5]]

## Approach 2: CASE Statements

An approach with [`CASE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724) statements (create formula #1 and #2 at the Data Source-level; formula 3 can be created at the Data Source-level or Chart-level if required):

**1) Column 1 (A)**

```
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Column 1, "A") THEN "A"
  ELSE NULL
END
```

**2) Column 2 (TRUE)**

```
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Column 2, "TRUE") THEN "TRUE"
  ELSE NULL
END
```

**3) Column 1 (A) / Column 2 (TRUE)**

```
COUNT(Column 1 (A)) / COUNT(Column 2 (TRUE))
```

Added a [New Page to the Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/e2fcf68c-3d56-45f2-aa6d-1f3ab972bcfb/page/iY3GB) to demonstrate as well as a GIF showing the process above:

[image: 8]]